# Faster way to perform function calculation in Python?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I'm interested in whether there is a way to further improve a "fast" version of a function used in a homework assignment I received recently (I've already submitted the completed work).

```
from math import log

def func_fast(mass, density):
    return sum(map((log(mass * density)).__truediv__, range(1,10001)))

def func_slow(mass, density): 
    total = 0.0 
    for i in range(10000): 
        masslog = log(mass * density) 
        total += masslog/(i+1)

    return total

mass = 2.5 
density = 12.0
```

The fast version times in around 2-2.5ish seconds while the slow version nets 6-7 seconds.

Comment: Your numbers (performance ones) do not add up. When I run those functions I get results in 0.009 to 0.025 seconds depending on the run... My linux box (2 yr old), is not that much faster than yours.... is it?

Answer (score 8):

This continues from Jaime's post.

This can be trivially sped up to \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ by caching `sum(1/j for j in range(1, 10001)) = 9.787606036044348`. Then one just does

```
def func_O1(mass, density):
    # 9.7876... = sum(1/j for j in range(1, 10001))
    return log(mass * density) * 9.787606036044348
```

This gives a speedup by a factor of 3000.

If the limit (10000) is varied, use [an approximation for the harmonic series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/404843/1763356):

```
from math import log

def harmonic(n):
    gamma = 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992
    return gamma + log(n) + 0.5/n - 1./(12*n**2) + 1./(120*n**4)

def func_fastest(mass, density):
    return log(mass * density) * harmonic(10000)
```

`harmonic` is inaccurate below \$n \approx 120\$ so it would make sense to cache exact values up to `harmonic(120)`. Note that whilst this is an approximation, for \$n\$ greater than \$120\$ it's exact \$\pm 1\text{eps}\$ whereas the summation gets steadily worse.

This only speeds up the function by a factor of 500.

Comment: I don't hear "only by a factor of 500" too often, made my day! ;-) I suppose the divisions are what's taking the most time in your `harmonic` call, so it may not make much of a difference, but the premature optimizer in me would rewrite  that as `n2 = n*n; n4 = n2*n2` and use those in the series expansion. Or if willing to give up some numerical precision, even better, `1_2n = 1 / (2*n); 1_4n2 = 1_2n*1_2n; 1_16n4 = 1_4n2*1_4n2` and then hardcode the decimal expansions of `1/3` and `2/15` for the last two terms.

Comment: @Jaime Best I could figure out is `((6.*n - 1.) * n2 + 0.1) / (12. * n4)` (courtesy of WolframAlpha). That makes it more like a factor of ~1000. I'll think I'll leave it in the comments, though!

Comment: Amazing. Well done!

Answer (score 3):

The speed-up you are seeing is mostly from removing the calculation of the logarithm from inside the inner loop, and instead reusing the value. This performs only about 10% slower than your `fast_func`, and is infinitely more readable:

```
def func_slow(mass, density):
    total = 0
    masslog = log(mass*density)
    for j in range(1, 10001):
        total += 1. / j
    return masslog * total
```

And if you want to squeeze those last drops of performance, the speed of the following code is marginally, if at all, slower than `fast_func`, and is also much more Pythonic and readable:

```
def func(mass, density):
    return log(mass * density) * sum(1/j for j in range(1, 10001))
```

While they stayed in the language, and are therefore fair game, reading [Guido's 10 year old essay](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) on how he planned to get rid of `reduce`, `map`, `lambda` and `filter` for Python 3 will probably have you looking at those a little differently: I for one always try to come up with more Pythonic alternatives when tempted to use them.